# MVVM in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, devforce

I know I'm MVVM in WPF I do not know how this Silverlight implementation layered on top tips to help me (I'd Entity Framwork for the model I use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) is a great framework for implementing MVVM in WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: i need sample project for MVVM Light for silverlight and connect with SqlServer, thanks

Comment: You're not going to get a perfect sample to suit your project. First take a look here http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/ for samples on MVVM. You can then extend it to include your SQLServer.

Answer (score 2):

You will do MVVM same way as you do it in WPF. But since Silverlight runs on client - you can't use EF there. Your choices will be to use RIA Services OR buy something like DevForce. I'm using DevForce and it allows you to write pretty much same LINQ queries on a client.